# Как получить элемент из массива php с тем же названием?

Tags: php

подскажите пожалуйста как сравнивать эти 2 массива. Дела в том что есть карточка ресторана. В ресторане можно проводить определенные мероприятия. В админ панели есть уже 9 вариантов мероприятий что можно произвести. Для конкретного ресторана выбирается чекбоксами определенное мероприятия. После того как редактор выбирает нужное мы получаем в массиве . Пример такой

```
array(3) { [0]=> string(18) "Вечеринка" [1]=> string(14) "Свадьба" [2]=> string(12) "Фуршет" }
```

Так же у нас уж есть готовый массив который повторяется на всех карточках, массив всех возможный варинатов

```
array(

            0 => [
              'img' => 'static/img/assets/club/a1.svg',
              'name' => 'Фуршет'
            ],
            1 => [
              'img' => 'static/img/assets/club/a2.svg',
              'name' => 'Вечеринка'
            ],
            2 => [
              'img' => 'static/img/assets/club/a3.svg',
              'name' => 'Свадьба'
            ],
            3 => [
              'img' => 'static/img/assets/club/a4.svg',
              'name' => 'Детский праздник'
            ],
            4 => [
              'img' => 'static/img/assets/club/a5.svg',
              'name' => 'Банкет'
            ],
            5 => [
              'img' => 'static/img/assets/club/a6.svg',
              'name' => 'День рождения и юбилей'
            ],
            6 => [
              'img' => 'static/img/assets/club/a7.svg',
              'name' => 'Конференции'
            ],
            7 => [
              'img' => 'static/img/assets/club/a8.svg',
              'name' => 'Тренинги'
            ],
            8 => [
              'img' => 'static/img/assets/club/a9.svg',
              'name' => 'Съемки'
            ],
          )
```

Вопрос, как можно сделать такое. Мы проходимся циклу по первому массиву из 3 элементов. Ищем данный элемент из 2 массива по значению name и получаем его ключ, дабы можно было получить еще и 'img' . Вопрос в реализации поиска по имени. Спасибо

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
    if (in_array($value['name'], $form_array, true) {
        echo $key;
        }
}
```

Comment: пожалуйста, оставляйте чуть более развёрнутые ответы. [постарайтесь рассказать обо всех нюансах, которые могут возникнуть при решении проблемы по вашему сценарию. изложите свои предложения. возможен и краткий ответ, но чем подробнее и понятнее он будет изложен, тем лучше](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$srch=array("0"=>"Вечеринка", "1"=>"Свадьба", "2"=>"Фуршет");

$arr=array("0" => [
              'img' => 'static/img/assets/club/a1.svg',
              'name' => 'Фуршет'
            ],
            "1" => [
              'img' => 'static/img/assets/club/a2.svg',
              'name' => 'Вечеринка'
            ],
            "2" => [
              'img' => 'static/img/assets/club/a3.svg',
              'name' => 'Свадьба'
            ],
            "3" => [
              'img' => 'static/img/assets/club/a4.svg',
              'name' => 'Детский праздник'
            ],
            "4" => [
              'img' => 'static/img/assets/club/a5.svg',
              'name' => 'Банкет'
            ],
            "5" => [
              'img' => 'static/img/assets/club/a6.svg',
              'name' => 'День рождения и юбилей'
            ],
            "6" => [
              'img' => 'static/img/assets/club/a7.svg',
              'name' => 'Конференции'
            ],
            "7" => [
              'img' => 'static/img/assets/club/a8.svg',
              'name' => 'Тренинги'
            ],
            "8" => [
              'img' => 'static/img/assets/club/a9.svg',
              'name' => 'Съемки'
            ],
          );


foreach ($arr as $key => $value) {


foreach ($srch as $key2 => $value2) {

if($value['name']==$value2){

$res[$value['name']]=$value['img'];

}
  
}

}

print_r($res);

?>
```